# SDL surface inside another GUI component?

Tags: sdl

Is there a way to host an SDL surface inside another GUI component so that SDL is not at the top-level? For instance, could I put an SDL surface inside a Java JPanel or other widget?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SDL website has several examples of how to do this: http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/FAQ_GUI

I'm not sure about Java, but you can definitely do it in C/C++ with GTK+